# How to remove button from Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm creating charts with the Highcharts library and I wonder how to remove the 2 little buttons on the right corner which one you can print and download graphs and I'd like to add a new one.

Maybe someone could help me?

Comment: Inspect them via firebug, if they have identities or other things. use css selectors and call .remove() method on them.

Comment: use firebug and find those particular button ids, and in your css you can say to display:none for that particular id or class

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Try adding `exporting: { enabled: false }` to your chart generation.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works :D. Maybe would you know how can i add a new one ?

Comment: No, not really creating a new one. But maybe you can modify one of the print/export buttons. The documentation hints in this direction http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#exporting-buttons ... playing with the `onClick`.

Comment: `exporting: false` is enough

Answer (score 13):

Check this to create new button:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fXHB5/3496/

```
exporting: {
    buttons: [
        {
            symbol: 'diamond',
            x: -62,
            symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
            hoverSymbolFill: '#779ABF',
            _titleKey: 'printButtonTitle',
            onclick: function() {
                alert('click!')
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This jsfiddle doesn't work anymore. "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.highcharts.com/js/testing-exporting.js"

Answer (score 9):

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

> You have to disable only the contextButton.

Answer (score 9):

The best way to replace the hamburger icon is to disable the navigation buttonOptions, then create your own menu and customize the context one by one as stated in the    [documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview). From here you can use any icon you want with your own dropdown menu.

This disables the hamburger icon.

```
navigation: {
buttonOptions: {
  enabled: false
  }
 }
```

This is how you customize export options for your own list.

```
$('#print').click(function() {
chart.print();
});
$('#pdf').click(function() {
chart.exportChart({
  type: 'application/pdf',
  filename: 'my-pdf'
 });
});
$('#png').click(function() {
chart.exportChart({
  type: 'image/png',
  filename: 'my-png'
 });
});
$('#jpeg').click(function() {
chart.exportChart({
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  filename: 'my-jpeg'
 });
});
$('#svg').click(function() {
chart.exportChart({
  type: 'image/svg+xml',
  filename: 'my-svg'
 });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/christopf85/g4s1L10f/)

Comment: Thanks buddy, this helped after 6 years to hide the hamburger icon without disabling the exporting ;)

Comment: note this fix also removes change selection for x axis labels (if any)

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou bastante. nesse exemplo ta foltando o "viewfullscrean" então pra quem estiver precisando https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1ga2fqL0/

Comment: feliz por poder ajudar!

Answer (score 1):

```
exporting:false,
```

Add the above code to disable export option.

Answer (score 0):

@dgw has the right idea to remove the export buttons, but I wasn't happy with the "and I'd like to add a new one" suggestions until I realized I should just make the buttons [outside the graph](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/members/series-setdata/).  Unless your data is static, you don't really know if there's room to display your controls.

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>
<button id="button" class="autocompare">new button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is:
you can just remove import of "node_modules/highcharts/modules/exporting.js" from the whole project if you don't need it at all.

That was a solution for me!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to update the `exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems` array to only include the menu items you want. Below is an example that excludes the "Print Chart" and "View Full Screen" options.

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            menuItems: ["downloadPNG", "downloadJPEG", "downloadPDF", "downloadSVG"]
        }
    }
}
```

[Highcharts Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/menuitemdefinitions/)