# Control HighCharts export options

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I am using HighCharts. Now just by importing `exporting.js` file I get all the format for exporting like png, jpeg, PDF, SVG, CSV and EXCEL. What should I do to restrict some options? Like if I want only export to excel functionality how do I restrict other options?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/37/highcharts-export-clientside and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685681/how-to-remove-button-from-highcharts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get default options this way:

```
var options = Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems;
```

Now, simply modify that array:

```
options.splice(4, 1); // remove PDF
```

And use in options:

```
exporting: {
  buttons: {
    contextButton: {
      menuItems: options
    }
  }
},
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pscjzhe4/283/

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-type="application/vnd.ms-excel">XLS</button>
```

You can use `exportChartLocal`:

```
 $('#exportExcel').click(function(){
      var chart = $('#example-1').highcharts();
      chart.exportChartLocal({ type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel' });
});
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/pscjzhe4/282/)

Comment: Thanks @IsraGab for your answer. I have done this.The thing is I do not want all options for export. I only want 'Download to XLS'.  How do I hide or restrict other options?

Comment: I think you are not understanding my question. I do not want to show options like 'Download PNG image', ''Download JPEG image'' etc. I just want 'Download XLS' and no other options. How do I do that?

Comment: Just don't display the options, I gave you a code and a fiddle. Can you see there  "Download JPEG" etc... ??

Comment: Oops! I was checking the chart context menu on top right corner. Yes, I can work with that button 'XLS'. Thanks.

Comment: By the way is there any way to restrict options in that chart context menu?

Comment: OK! now I understand what you were asking for  :). Sorry, I didn't pay attention to this button. If I were you, I would hide it and customize another dropdown `navigation: {
            buttonOptions: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },  ` or customise it if you want

Comment: If you want to customize it and let only excel you can do `Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems;
options.splice(0, 7); `

Comment: But if I were you I would prefere to do my own  dropdown/button. If highcharts is changing the order in this menu your code won't be good

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
          contextButton{
              menuItems:['printChart', 'downloadPNG', 'downloadCSV', 'downloadXLS']
          }
        }
      }
```

You can get more menu items from this link to suit your needs --> https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems